# Laravel 5 Dynamic morph method

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

I'm building a package which heavily relies on a morph many relationship. As usual with this relationship it is required to define the relationships like so:

```
public function foos()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Foo', 'barable');
}
```

This obviously works fine and there is no problem here.

The thing is though that there are many of these relationships that need to be defined. And I'd like to just loop through them and building them automagically to make configuring the package easier.

I have tried the following:

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if($name == 'foos') {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Foo', 'barable');
    }
}
```

This does not initiate the query to retrieve the data. It gets called, but it doesn't return data.

The __call function seemed logical to me too, but that just breaks Laravel. As far as I can tell it picks up everything that's being called in the class.

An alternative now is to include a trait and make the programmer fill in these relations in the publishable file, but that just feels wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a two step answer. You need a fix for eager loading and one for lazy loading.

The eager loader takes the __call() function specified in the model.php and redirects to it if the statement fails.

```
public function __call($method, $arguments){
    if(in_array($method, ['bars'])) {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Bar', 'barable');
    }
    return parent::__call($method, $arguments);
}
```

The lazy loader checks if the method exists, which obviously it doesn't. Adding it to your model and adding an "OR" statement will make those work too. The original function also resides in model.php. Adding:

```
 || in_array($key, $this->morphs)
```

Will make the function work as expected and thus results in:

```
public function getRelationValue($key)
{
    // If the key already exists in the relationships array, it just means the
    // relationship has already been loaded, so we'll just return it out of
    // here because there is no need to query within the relations twice.
    if ($this->relationLoaded($key)) {
        return $this->relations[$key];
    }

    // If the "attribute" exists as a method on the model, we will just assume
    // it is a relationship and will load and return results from the query
    // and hydrate the relationship's value on the "relationships" array.
    if (method_exists($this, $key) || in_array($key, $this->morphs)) {
        return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key);
    }
}
```